# usage of textscan in Octave 3.8.2

Tags: matlab, octave, textscan

The following is working fine when reading a data file of *"1.2D+02 3.23D+01* ...." in *matlab*;

```
tempvs = textscan ( input_unit, '%f', N );
tempvs = cell2mat(tempvs);
tempvs = double(tempvs);
```

But, the same would not work (does not recognize "D" numbers) in octave (ver. 3.8.2) so i modified a little like the following;

```
tempvs = textscan ( input_unit, '%s', N );
tempvs = cell2mat(tempvs);
values = zeros(N,1);
for i = 1: N
   values(i) = str2num(tempvs{i,1});
end
```

Is there other efficient way to do the job? 
Thanks in advance for youe help.

**NOTE:** changing data file into "*1.2E+02 3.23E+01* ...." form is not an option, already tried line-by-line reading using fgetl but its slow.

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` the file, read all at once `fread(fid, "char=>char").'` and try `textscan ( regexprep(input_unit,"D","E"), '%f' )` when your file looks like `input_unit="1.2D+02 3.23D+01"` everywhere. This should be blazing fast as long as your file fits into your RAM. But I dunno what `D` numbers are?